# keycloak spring adapter scope mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using spring boot `2.2.5` and keycloak `9.0.2` with it's `spring-boot-adapter`.
I've created a client scope and assigned it to my custom client (public client). When I decode the JWT token I can also see that scope in `scope` claim.
While I'am able to use roles mapped through keycloak adapter I didn't found way how to map scope. I mean I'd like to use something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_somescope')")` like described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization).

Is this possible with current keycloak's adapter implementation?

Thanks